# Is there a way to use netcat to transfer a gzipped file to a remote destination?

Tags: remote, archive

I have an archive I need to transfer to a remote destination but the target drive is not big enough to hold both the compressed archive and the uncompressed files.

I wonder if there are some utilities which can decompress the archive as the data arrives, rather than having to receive the whole thing then decompress it.

netcat is what seems to show up in my searches but I am open to any alternatives.

Comment: curl http://URL/FILE.tar.gz | tar xz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the sending side:

```
dd if=somefile.gz bs=32M |nc server 7000
```

On the receiving side:

```
nc -l -p 7000 | gzip -dfc|dd bs=32M of=somefile
```

or if it is a tar.gz

```
nc -l -p 7000 | gzip -dfc|tar -xvf -
```

Comment: I am trying to execute if over a secure connection via SSH. I first create a tunnel - ssh root@remote -L 7000:localhost:7000. But after I try to send via  dd if=/archives/file.gz bs=32M | nc localhost 7000 on the local side, an error appera channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused. Any idea what it could be. I am doing some searching anyway

Comment: You have to first establish the receiving side and then the sender.